# google maps distance api with coordinates

Tags: xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have read about google distance matrix and output to json or xml http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters
this is the original link from google http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Vancouver+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=

my database have only coordinates so i try this one bellow with only coordinates but i get error **INVALID_REQUEST**
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=38.078459,23.734718|38.078833,23.736843&mode=bicycling&language=el&key=
anyone can help on this?

Comment: There is no destination parameter in the "INVALID REQUEST".  Are you including one?  If I add arbitrary destination coordinates I get a response (albeit ZERO_RESULTS).

Comment: 38.078459,23.734718 is the first point and 38.078833,23.736843 is the second point that need to be calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no destination parameter in the "INVALID REQUEST". If I add arbitrary destination coordinates I get a response (albeit ZERO_RESULTS):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=38.078459,23.734718|38.078833,23.736843&destinations=45,22|44,24&mode=bicycling&language=el&key=